# SLD Filter MAX function

Tags: geoserver, sld

'density' is a table column, which max value I want to get

```
<Rule>
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
    <ogc:PropertyName>density</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Mul>
    <ogc:Function name="max">
    <ogc:PropertyName>density</ogc:PropertyName> 
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>0.166</ogc:Literal> 
    </ogc:Mul>
    </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
    </ogc:Filter>
    <PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#96B6F3</CssParameter>
    <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Then I get message "Unable to find function max". What is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to not declaring OGC namespace in StyleLayerDescriptor of your SLD file, so the max function cannot be resolved. Try adding following line as an attribute of *StyleLayerDescriptor*:

```
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
```

Comment: Nope! This namespace is declared:
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">